# Jolt Transformation - json contains resut format

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

The body of the request consists of 2 objects, one of which is the payload, and the other is a description, since the payload must be transformed for transmission to the next system.
Please, help write a specification for such a format:

body:

```
{
"input":{
    "items":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"items1",
            "statusId":5
        },
        {
            "id":7,
            "name":"items7",
            "statusId":2
        },

        ...

        {
            "id":N, // any number
            "name":"itemsN",
            "statusId":1
        }
    ]
},
"output":[
    {
        "target":"sg_id",
        "source":"id",
        "type":"list"
    },
    {
        "target":"sg_name",
        "source":"name",
        "type":"list"
    }
]}
```

result:

```
{
"items":{
    "sg_id":[
        1,
        7,
        ...
        N
    ],
    "sg_name":[
        "items1",
        "items7",
        ...
        "itemsN"
    ]
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **shift** operation through prepending desired aliases with the title(`item.`) of the array such as

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "input": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "id": "items.sg_id",
          "name": "items.sg_name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]
```